# Java Optaplanner - different computation on different machines

Tags: java, optaplanner

I have following problem with Optaplanner. We have solution that recieves bunch of locations (in our terms ticekets) with longtitude and latitude information. Those tickets are then optimized via Optaplanner library to get best sequence of tickets that are nearest. It is defacto vehicle routing problem.

Currently we increase maximum number of input tickets to be higher then 15. But I am facing strange issue. On my machine (Win 10, i7 with 4 cores, 16 GB RAM, SSD) everything works very well and 50 are optimized. Same on my friends machine which has a i7 CPU as well. But when I deploy application to production environment which is VMWare workstation with Intel Xeon CPU computation is very slow and computation spend time is reached and tickets are not optimized.

We tried more VMWare environments with different config and still no good result (but I didn't configured them).  I tried to increase timeout of computation but It only gets to compute fairly low computation steps as well. I cannot simulate it my local machine (I also tried to run in VMWare installed on my PC and all went OK). I found out that heuristic phase of computing gives really different values so maybe this is source of problem.

Here is my optaplanner config file:

```
<solver>
    <solutionClass>com.keystone.core.domain.solver.TicketOptimizationSolution</solutionClass>
    <entityClass>com.keystone.core.domain.solver.Visit</entityClass>
    <entityClass>com.keystone.core.domain.solver.Appearance</entityClass>

    <scoreDirectorFactory>
        <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT_LONG</scoreDefinitionType>
        <scoreDrl>com/keystone/ticketOptimizer/solver/ticketOptimizerScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl>
        <initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN</initializingScoreTrend>
    </scoreDirectorFactory>

    <termination>
        <secondsSpentLimit>25</secondsSpentLimit>
    </termination>

    <constructionHeuristic>
        <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
    </constructionHeuristic>

    <localSearch>
        <termination>
            <terminationCompositionStyle>OR</terminationCompositionStyle>
            <secondsSpentLimit>20</secondsSpentLimit>
            <unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>5</unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>
        </termination>
        <unionMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
                <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
                <selectionOrder>SHUFFLED</selectionOrder>
            </changeMoveSelector>
            <swapMoveSelector/>
            <subChainChangeMoveSelector>
                <subChainSelector>
                    <maximumSubChainSize>50</maximumSubChainSize>
                </subChainSelector>
                <selectReversingMoveToo>true</selectReversingMoveToo>
            </subChainChangeMoveSelector>
            <subChainSwapMoveSelector>
                <selectReversingMoveToo>true</selectReversingMoveToo>
            </subChainSwapMoveSelector>
        </unionMoveSelector>
        <acceptor>​
            <stepCountingHillClimbingSize>400</stepCountingHillClimbingSize>
            <entityTabuSize>5</entityTabuSize>
        </acceptor>
        <forager>
            <acceptedCountLimit>1</acceptedCountLimit>
        </forager>
    </localSearch>
</solver>
```

Here are my drolls rules:

```
// ############################################################################
// Hard constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "ticketNotDoneDueDate"
    when
        Visit($ticket: ticket, $departureTime: departureTime)
        Ticket($departureTime > dueDate, $dueDate: dueDate) from $ticket
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $dueDate - $departureTime);
end

// ############################################################################
// Soft constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "distanceToPreviousStandstill"
    when
        $visit : Visit(previousAppearance != null, $distanceFromPreviousStandstill : distanceFromPreviousStandstill)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, - (int)$distanceFromPreviousStandstill);
end
```

And finally stack strace from my machine and prod machine.
[image: My local PC]

[image]

How can I solve this issue? I am really out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible that the Construction Heuristic has a different score if it completed entirely (and it did according to both logs) with environmentMode REPRODICIBLE (which is the default). Check your solver config to prove that you're not using environmentMode NON_REPRODICBLE (which used to be called PRODUCTION).

If it still differs with environmentMode REPRODICIBLE, turn on trace logging on both and show where it differs.

The difference in score calculation speed is not surprising: cloud VM, containers, GAE, etc often have less than 1 physical CPU per process in the normal accounts. I've often witnessed them to be slower than local machines, except for the dedicated cloud offerings (for example OpenShift Dedicated instead of OpenShift Online or GCE instead of GAE).

Comment: Hello Geofrey, thank you very much for your answer! I have environmentMode REPRODICIBLE, so this is not cause of problems. I tried to run application on PC with realy slow CPU - old Celeron - and all went well. So that from my point of view this isnt bug in my code. What do you suggest than? To run it on dedicated PC? It seems that customer dont believe me that will solve it but I dont know what else to recommend

Comment: I examined logs of heuristic phase turned on TRACE level logging. The very first difference is at calculation of first move:
My local PC:
`move index (0), score (-16init/0hard/0soft), move (Visit(ticket=Ticket(id=1178172, priorityOfTicket=10, dueDate=1502316000, estimatedTimeOfCompletion=1800, location=Location(latitude=29.666109, longitude=-95.198724))) {null -> Domicile(nextVisit=null, location=Location(latitude=29.683423, longitude=-95.258453), departureTime=1502290342)}).`

Comment: remote VMWare:

`Move index (0), score (-16init/0hard/-7343soft), move (Visit(ticket=Ticket(id=1178172, priorityOfTicket=10, dueDate=1502316000, estimatedTimeOfCompletion=1800, location=Location(latitude=29.666109, longitude=-95.198724))) {null -> Domicile(nextVisit=null, location=Location(latitude=29.683423, longitude=-95.258453), departureTime=1502290342)}).`

as you can see SOFT score is different at differes more and more each other step

Comment: Wierd. Interesting. Exact same move generates different score. Run both in environmentMode `FULL_ASSERT`. Than - again on both - add a `<assertionScoreDirectorFactory>` with the same EasyJavaScoreCalculator to prove that the rules output the correct score.

Comment: @BerťasDostál Did you figure out what's causing this? When you do, do share as an answer: I want to know.

Comment: I got the same problem but on the same machine - once reading input data from XML (works fine) and JSON (created from this XML using Jackson). The score is totally different although when using debugger these 2 solutions objects I get are perfectly the same.

Comment: Hello @Geoffrey De Smet, unfortunally when I tried run both in environmentMode FULL_ASSERT, it never finished and got stucked for hours on my local machine. We tried solution on this server https://www.netcup.eu/bestellen/produkt.php?produkt=1769 (they claim 2 dedicated cores, it was AMD CPUs) but still got same bad results. Do you know any cloud service with dedicated CPUs when we can try it?

Comment: I tried unit test with smaller amount of tickets and got error (with FULL_ASSERT):

Comment: VariableListener corruption: the entity (Visit(ticket=Ticket(id=null, priorityOfTicket=0, dueDate=150, estimatedTimeOfCompletion=10, location=Location(latitude=10.0, longitude=10.0))))'s shadow variable (Visit.arrivalTi
me)'s corrupted value (null) changed to uncorrupted value (0) after all VariableListeners were triggered without changes to the genuine variables.

Comment: Maybe the VariableListener class (WorkFinishTimeUpdatingVariableListener) for that shadow variable (Visit.arrivalTime) forgot to update it when one of its sources changed after completedAction (Initial score calculated).
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(AbstractScoreDirector.java:461)

Comment: In listener WorkFinishTimeUpdatingVariableListener in method afterVariableChanged i call this:

Comment: Appearance previousAppearance = sourceVisit.getPreviousAppearance();
        Visit shadowVisit = sourceVisit;
        long departureTime = previousAppearance != null ? previousAppearance.getDepartureTime() : 0;
        long arrivalTime = calculateArrivalTime(shadowVisit, departureTime);

Comment: while (shadowVisit != null && !Objects.equals(shadowVisit.getDepartureTime(), arrivalTime)) {
            scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(shadowVisit, "arrivalTime");
            shadowVisit.setArrivalTime(arrivalTime);
            scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(shadowVisit, "arrivalTime");
            departureTime = shadowVisit.getDepartureTime();
            shadowVisit = shadowVisit.getNextVisit();
            arrivalTime = calculateArrivalTime(shadowVisit, departureTime);
        }

Comment: **Make sure your local runs are reproducible first.** If FULL_ASSERT (which is also reproducible) finds any score corruptions, fix those first and then turn it back to REPRODUCIBLE.